# Android Robotium Test for Non activity class

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Can anyone tell me how can I write Robotium tests for non activity classes?
I have seen lot of example for activity classes but not for non activity classes.
Is it possible?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robotium is mostly useful for interacting with your app in a test case. These interactions are usually with activities.

If you want to test other classes, there's no need to use Robotium. You might look into [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) for running tests in the JVM on your computer.

Comment: I have a separate class with all the listeners like the onClick,onLongClick,onItemSelectedListener etc. So this is basically for interaction with the application. What do you suggest I should do?